# Duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_ with private pod

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, cocoapods

I know there are a lot of questions have been asked on Stack regarding that issue. I still cant figure out what wrong. I created private static library with Cocoapods. Then via `podfile` I integrate it in my project.(very common). Every time I receive the following error:

```
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ARNStyles in:
    /Users/My Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testApp-evjgwyqlioietzfdxpqntltcyfhn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-testApp-YooshUiIos.a(ARNStyles-B1E440918306D831.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ARNStyles in:
    /Users/My Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testApp-evjgwyqlioietzfdxpqntltcyfhn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-testApp-YooshUiIos.a(ARNStyles-B1E440918306D831.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What did I try :

- To Run it on test clean project.
- Changed LinkingFlags in the `podsec` in the `project` and in the `pod` itself.

  There is only `.h .m` of that files.I didn't import `.m` file.

I read more or less all the question regarding that issue.

Did any one had the same problem?(or what else can I try)

**Edit**
its probably my `podsec` I have several other libraries and that get compiled with the same project.

**Edit**
I made all my files in one podsec instead of splitting them to different podsecs.And it compiled. (very strange)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: ARNStyles is in your build phases twice

Comment: Max Macled, I am trying on an empty project my Build Phases are empty for the project.

Comment: Max Macleod is right.  Perhaps you have it in the "link with libraries" and also setup in the linker build settings?